# Get the event.target in formik Select onChange - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, onchange, formik

Following is the Select in my `withFormik` Form. Which is working fine.

```
<Select
    id="userList"
    name="userList"
    value={userList.names}
    initialValue={values.userList}
    className="select-box"
    onChange={setFieldValue}
/>
```

But now on the basis of value selected I need to add/remove class from the select. so I tried e but it is returning the field name only

```
<Select
    id="userList"
    name="userList"
    value={userList.names}
    initialValue={values.userList}
    className="select-box"
    onChange={e => {
        console.log(e) // => userList
    }}
/>
```

I even tried this but no luck

```
<Select
    id="userList"
    name="userList"
    value={userList.names}
    initialValue={values.userList}
    className="select-box"
    onChange={(field, value) => {
        console.log(field) // Response => userList
        setFieldValue(field, value)
    }}
/>
```

How can I access the event in onchange as on the basis of value I need to add / remove class from the select. Something like -

```
handleChange = e => {
    // Here e is refering to the Select
    if (e.target.value) {
      e.target.classList.remove("gray");
      e.target.classList.add("black");
    } else {
      e.target.classList.remove("black");
      e.target.classList.add("gray");
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 3):

`<Select />` as a controlled component would require the `value` prop to use the state's `selected` value.

`value` prop is **not** meant for the `<option>` values.

Thus, you can have something like:

```
state = {
  selected: '',
}

handleChange = e => {
  const selected = e.target.value; // selected name
  switch(selected) {
    // change class
  }
  this.setState({
    selected
  });
}

<Select value={this.state.selected} onChange={handleChange}>
 {userList.names.map(user =>
   <options value={user.name}>{user.name}</option>
 )}
</Select>
```